# gstatic.com resolves to local isp

Tags: dns-domain

In the light of Snowden revelations I become very paranoid. Yesterday I did a `netstat -t -p` and from my browser there were several connections pointing to my isp. I had only 2 pages open.

Trying to find source of the connection, pinged all urls that the browser connected to.

gstatic.com was pointing to one of my isp ip. Did a dig all A section was full of ips from my isp. Is that normal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely normal. `gstatic.com` is used for static Google content (Javascript, pictures, CSS, stuff like that which is the same for all users), and one advantage of offloading static content onto its own domain is that they can then use a CDN to put that content as close as possible to users. So, Google puts copies of the content on servers in your ISP's datacenter in order to speed up page loads.

Comment: Well, probably, anyway. ;)